# Which SIGHASH type we have to append at the end of the trimmed transaction in OP_CHECKSIG

Tags: transactions, validation, sighash-flags

how to know which sighash type we have to append to the trimmed transaction at the time of input scripts verification, take referance from the below example

{
"version": 2,
"locktime": 0,
"vin": [
{
"txid": "f7268fdc3dd4ab2ce606a9857f321f9c9d94a7cc4ca7d31db481938ce222403e",
"vout": 28,
"prevout": {
"scriptpubkey": "76a9145ae0dedcb9a96b8d4310e4ff137a22e0233258e988ac",
"scriptpubkey_asm": "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 OP_PUSHBYTES_20 5ae0dedcb9a96b8d4310e4ff137a22e0233258e9 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
"scriptpubkey_type": "p2pkh",
"scriptpubkey_address": "19HXCYbrynpvTMYkQoneBgo3xEnXPFDd4z",
"value": 150653
},
"scriptsig": "483045022100cfa7d65576fafd8f827904a1292b55d234898c1e444cd2dfc05f5e15b6f69e4402200b7ea6a9e3da80ea771fe1170795adcbea88d67eb8d82828e85d4b5883b9f9a80121038e464810ac06e1a7589e58bd9050ff1fc4d4768f00aaeedb2d4b5c231ac8851d",
"scriptsig_asm": "OP_PUSHBYTES_72 3045022100cfa7d65576fafd8f827904a1292b55d234898c1e444cd2dfc05f5e15b6f69e4402200b7ea6a9e3da80ea771fe1170795adcbea88d67eb8d82828e85d4b5883b9f9a801 OP_PUSHBYTES_33 038e464810ac06e1a7589e58bd9050ff1fc4d4768f00aaeedb2d4b5c231ac8851d",
"witness": null,
"is_coinbase": false,
"sequence": 4294967293,
"inner_redeemscript_asm": null
}
],
"vout": [
{
"scriptpubkey": "0014bc2870381de4d706a92105419f0c3072e26532d1",
"scriptpubkey_asm": "OP_0 OP_PUSHBYTES_20 bc2870381de4d706a92105419f0c3072e26532d1",
"scriptpubkey_type": "v0_p2wpkh",
"scriptpubkey_address": "bc1qhs58qwqauntsd2fpq4qe7rpswt3x2vk3krdvhh",
"value": 147107
}
]
}